# PHP version on my localhost and web server

Tags: php, wordpress, web-deployment

I just started developing a website on my local host and I realized that my localhost and my web server have different PHP versions.

I have downloaded XAMPP with PHP version of 7.2.20. My host / web server is running on PHP 7.0

When I will migrate/upload my website from localhost to live, will I have any issues with the PHP versions being different? Do I have to reinstall XAMPP using php version 7.0?

Comment: you can check the changelogs in the manual to see if it will be an issue

Comment: See [Migrating from PHP 7.0.x to PHP 7.1.x](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.php) and [Migrating from PHP 7.1.x to PHP 7.2.x](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.php).

Comment: Where do I even check ?

Comment: Also see [PHP 7 ChangeLog](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php).